# Searching custom model method with other fields with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, methods, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

In my project, Properties belong to Titles and I have a custom model method (ex: "somedate") which extracts a field in one of the associated Title records.  I'm using Ransack to search and sort Properties and would like to include a field in my search form for my somedate method.

I'm currently calling <%= property.somedate(id) %> in my search output table via the controller index method (e.g. @search = Property.search(params[:q]) which I'd like to search.  I assume that I need a form_tag but I'm unsure how to process the somedate params once it's in the form.  How should I do this?

Comment: Please include the supporting code for the question.